# Details about the types of the filtered frame used in FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, frame, multimedia

I am new in multimedia analysis.

I am trying to extract key frames from .*mp4* and .*flv* format videos by using **FFmpeg**. The problem is that I was confused by the parameters used in the [command](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect) (Select only I-frames).

```
select='eq(pict_type\,I)'
```

The parameters are used to choose the types of filtered frame and It can assume one of the following values:

> I P B S SI SP BI

After searching on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types), I have got some basic concepts on I, P, B frames but still cannot tell the difference among S, SI, SP and BI. How to decide which type of frame should I use in my command line?

[Update]

I found some of the definitions of these terms in *The H.264 Advanced Video Compression Standard*, Second Edition.

- SI: Intra-coded slice used for switching between coded bitstreams
  (H.264)
- SP: Inter-coded slice used for switching between coded
  bitstreams

Comment: You want the I-frames as they are fully specified pictures, they don't depend on other frames.

Comment: I think you can just use `select=key` for keyframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SI & SP picture types are H264 specific. They are provided for various purposes like bit-stream switching, splicing, random access, fast-forward, fast reverse, and error resilience/recovery. They are almost same as I & P type. SP pict-type allows to produce identical reconstruction even if different reference pictures are used.

BI type is WMV9 or VC-1 specific. A BI frame is an I-frame that isn't a keyframe; it is like a B-frame, except intra-only.

S type is S-VOP (Sprite Video Object Plane) and specific to Mpeg4 sprite coding.

These picture types are rarely used in video coding, you may want to ignore them.